# How save insert scripts in separate sql files in MySqlWorkbent?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How save insert sctipts in separate sql files in MySqlWorkbent? I can create database with tables but I didn't find how to save separately or with db creation script inserts scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what your issue with the Workbench is.
Are you trying to save insert scripts based on the content of your database?

If so, then you can open the connection and connect to your database (Workspace - SQL Development).

Choose your schema in the object browser window (left) and right-click a table to select 'Send to SQL Editor' -> Select All Statement.

Then you run the query and on the results you choose 'Export' from the toolbutton menu - Save as type - SQL Insert statements.